# JavaFX waiting for a specific event

Tags: user-interface, javafx, click, user-input, actionevent

Actually I’m working on a GUI using javaFX. I’m writing a function that takes as input the action event of click over an image. Now inside this function I perform some actions and then I have to wait user clicks over another component of the interface. How can I do that without creating an external function called when I press on the second object that update a Boolean unlocking the execution of the first function in infinite while( !Boolean){} loop? Is possible use a sort of wait for user input function? Can I obtain the reference to the last action event performed by the user? Thanks a lot

Comment: You can handle many `Events` using the same `Event Handler`. You just have to use a `switch` or `if else` statement. Use `event.getSource().equals(yourSourceNode)`. In most cases, this is not recommended. Just create an `Event Handler` for each `Node`.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a "busy wait". Do not do that. Instead create a class to store the information you derive from the user actions, pass an instance of said class to your event handlers, and once you have received all user input finish your calculations/operations.

Comment: Ok the idea is this: I select the first image that is linked to a series of operation. I have to populate a class containing data and then send this class to the server but actually I don’t knew how to knew when all the data (setted clicking over the interface components) are updated or not. I mean I click over the first image then I have to set tre elements in a grid pane and save x and y coordinates inside the data class and finally send all to the server. This is my complete problem

Comment: First, take a look at this article on how to fix busy waiting which is what you described in your post: [avoid busy waiting](https://josephmate.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/how-to-avoid-busy-waiting/) and then post another question with code you've developed if you have issues with it

Comment: @GiorgioSofisti So, if only the user can decide when she/he is done then you need to add a way for the user to tell the application "I'm done! Now process my data." E.g. you could add a "Commit" button to your application. You collect data each time the user clicks on your images (without sending them to the server) and once the user clicks "Commit" you send the collected data to the server.